# There is an overflow error with my coding

Tags: excel, vba, loops, iteration

I am required to make an amortisation table for a fixed loan, where it is paid in equal annual instalments and the first payment to be made at the end of the first year. I am using variable interest rates and periods, however something is not correct about my code and I am not sure what.

I have tried stepping into but it highlights a lot and I am not sure what is wrong.

This is my code:

```
Sub Loan_Amort_VBR()

' This version modifies the fixed rate iteration model to accommodate 3 different
' interest rates specified by the user.

Dim initLoanAmount, LoanLife
Dim yrBegBal(100), YrEndBal(), finalBal
Dim ipPay(100, 2), intRate(1 To 100)
Dim per1, per2, per3, int1, int2, int3
Dim annPayment, annPmtOld
Dim OutputRow, Rowno, NoOfIter, BalTol
Dim OutputSheet, iCol, pCol

'************************************************************
' User inputs
'************************************************************
' Read in from data entered by user on worksheet
initLoanAmount = Cells(2, 2).Value 'initial loan balance
per1 = Cells(3, 2).Value 'Length of period 1
per2 = Cells(4, 2).Value
per3 = Cells(5, 2).Value
int1 = Cells(6, 2).Value 'Interest rate for period 1
int2 = Cells(7, 2).Value
int3 = Cells(8, 2).Value

LoanLife = per1 + per2 + per3
'************************************************************
' Programmer inputs
'************************************************************
OutputSheet = "Loan Amort VBR"
BalTol = 1 'Specifies desired accuracy
iCol = 1
pCol = 2
OutputRow = 12 'row below which repayment schedule would start

'************************************************************
' Preliminaries
'************************************************************
' Make the outSheet the active sheet
Worksheets(OutputSheet).Activate

' Clear previous data
Rows(OutputRow + 1 & ":" & OutputRow + 300).Select
Selection.Clear

ReDim YrEndBal(LoanLife) 'Redimension the array

'************************************************************
' Computations and output
'************************************************************
' Enter appropriate interest rates into the intRate array
For Rowno = 1 To LoanLife
If Rowno <= per1 Then
    intRate(Rowno) = int1
ElseIf Rowno <= per1 + per2 Then
    intRate(Rowno) = int2
Else
    intRate(rNum) = int3
End If
Next

annPayment = initLoanAmount * Application.Min(int1, int2, int3)
NoOfIter = 0 ' Counter for number of iterations

' This Do loop controls the iteration
Do While finalBal > BalTol Or finalBal = 0

    ' Initialize balance at the beginning of year 1
    yrBegBal(1) = initLoanAmount

    ' Loop to calculate and store year-by-year data
    For Rowno = 1 To LoanLife
        ipPay(Rowno, iCol) = yrBegBal(Rowno) * intRate(Rowno)
        ipPay(Rowno, pCol) = annPayment - ipPay(Rowno, iCol)
        YrEndBal(Rowno) = yrBegBal(Rowno) - ipPay(Rowno, pCol)

        yrBegBal(Rowno + 1) = YrEndBal(Rowno)
    Next Rowno

    finalBal = YrEndBal(LoanLife)
    annPmtOld = annPayment

    ' Calculate the next annual payment to try
    annPayment = annPayment + (finalBal * (1 + _
      Application.Max(int1, int2, int3)) ^ _
      (-LoanLife)) / LoanLife
    NoOfIter = NoOfIter + 1 ' Count iterations

Loop

'***************************************************************
' Output data to worksheet
'***************************************************************
For Rowno = 1 To LoanLife
    Cells(OutputRow + Rowno, 3).Value = Rowno 'Year number
    Cells(OutputRow + Rowno, 4).Value = yrBegBal(Rowno)
    Cells(OutputRow + Rowno, 5).Value = annPmtOld
    Cells(OutputRow + Rowno, 6).Value = ipPay(Rowno, iCol)
    Cells(OutputRow + Rowno, 7).Value = ipPay(Rowno, pCol)
    Cells(OutputRow + Rowno, 8).Value = YrEndBal(Rowno)
    Cells(OutputRow + Rowno, 9).Value = intRate(Rowno)
Next Rowno

' Print out number of iterations used
Cells(OutputRow + LoanLife + 4, 1).Value = "No. of iterations ="
Cells(OutputRow + LoanLife + 4, 2).Value = numOfIterations

'************************************************************
' Format data in table
'************************************************************
Range(Cells(OutputRow + 1, 4), Cells(OutputRow + LoanLife, 8)). _
  Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"

Range(Cells(OutputRow + 1, 9), Cells(OutputRow + LoanLife, 9)). _
  Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0#%"

End Sub
```

When I step into the code, these parts are highlighted yellow:

```
Sub Loan_Amort_VBR()
initLoanAmount = Cells(2, 2).Value 'initial loan balance
per1 = Cells(3, 2).Value 'Length of period 1
per2 = Cells(4, 2).Value
per3 = Cells(5, 2).Value
int1 = Cells(6, 2).Value 'Interest rate for period 1
int2 = Cells(7, 2).Value
int3 = Cells(8, 2).Value
LoanLife = per1 + per2 + per3
OutputSheet = "Loan Amort VBR"
BalTol = 1 'Specifies desired accuracy
iCol = 1
pCol = 2
OutputRow = 12 'row below which repayment schedule would start
Worksheets(OutputSheet).Activate
```

Comment: Before you even try to fix the problem, understand what that error mean. [Overflow Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/overflow-error-6)

Comment: A good practice would also definately be to use option explicit above your code to catch undeclared variables (which you currently have e.g. rNum and numOfIterations)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am still confused about the error

Comment: @JvdV it highlights this section when I do this and fix the other errors:     Cells(OutputRow + Rowno, 7).Value = ipPay(Rowno, pCol)

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow, it is generally more easy to get help if you also add the full error trace stack in your question as that helps identify the Issue easily.

Comment: Well, all your variables are declared as variant per default. Look into changing that. Working out which datatype you need might solve a lot of issues.

Comment: Emily, If you have a container which can hold 1 litre of water and you try to pour 2 litres in that container then what will happen?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes I understand that but I cannot see where there is the overflow

Comment: ok. Now once you undertsand that. Debug the code and visit the line which is giving you that error. Put a watch on the variable as well as where you are storing the value. Check both; the value and the type. You will have your answer :)

Comment: [Add a watch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/forms/add-a-watch-expression)